# imeediately requesting publish permissions on facebook session with android sdk

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to immediately request publish permissions on a just created user session and getting the following error because the session state is "CREATED" and not "OPENED"

```
"Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that is not currently open."
```

How can I immediately ask for publish permissions?  Is there any way I can authorize the new user and get the publish permissions in one single call?

final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session.isOpened())
{
    shareToFacebook(loadedImage, shareBody, session);
}
else
{

```
final StatusCallback callback = new StatusCallback() {
    public void call(Session thisSession, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (exception != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook permissions failed: " + exception.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            shareToFacebook(loadedImage, shareBody, thisSession);
        }
    }
};


//up the permissions and then post
if (session != null && !isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS,  session.getPermissions())) {

    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(ActivityFacts.this, PERMISSIONS);
    session.addCallback(callback);
    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
}
else
{
    //add user then up the permissions
    StatusCallback authorizeCallback = new StatusCallback() {
        public void call(Session thisSession, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (exception != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook login failed: " + exception.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(ActivityFacts.this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.addCallback(callback);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

            }
        }
    };


    OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(ActivityFacts.this);
    List<String> readPermissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    readPermissions.add("email");
    openRequest.setPermissions(readPermissions);
    openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
    openRequest.setCallback(authorizeCallback);
    session.openForRead(openRequest);
}
```

}